# Pyspark: Filter dataframe based on separate specific conditions

Tags: python, data-cleaning, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I select only certain entries that match my condition and from those entries, filter again using regex?

For instance, I have this data frame (df):

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | f | 5 | g |
| D | er | 2e | sd |
| F | g | 23sd | a |
| F | fgf | 45 | d |
| E | r | 3 | e |
| A | sd | 8f | dw |
| F | sd | 3h1 | d |

I would like to select those entries with 'F' value in col1, and filter again with regex ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) to get only entries with numbers and letters.

```
+----+----+----+----+         +----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|         |col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+         +----+----+----+----+ 
|   F|   g|23sd|   a|   -->   |   F|   g|23sd|   a|
|   F| fgf|  45|   d|         |   F|  sd| 3h1|   d|
|   F|  sd| 3h1|   d|         +----+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` method on Spark's [DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) API:

```
df_filtered = df.filter("df.col1 = F").collect()
```

which also supports regex

```py
pattern = r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
df_filtered_regex = df.filter([df_filtered.c.rlike(pattern) for c in df.columns]).collect()`
```